# How to add cookies in chrometemp folder

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, session-cookies

I opened the Cookies file in my chrome temp folder through sqlite and imported the cookies, but when I open the browser again, the cookies I added are gone.

Is there any way to add cookies?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
    opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opts.add_argument("user-data-dir='/YOUR CHROME DIR/'")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
```

remember to replace `'/YOUR CHROME DIR/'` ,

> `opts.add_argument("user-data-dir='/YOUR CHROME DIR/'")`

this line will store all your session data.